# c sharp, json deserialize square bracket with unknown key

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization, json.net

I have problem with deserialize json file with square brackets and unknown name keys. Maybe someone have some idea how to do it? I readed all similar question but nothing works.

json file

```
[
  {
    "item1": {
      "value1": "rhe5h45h",
      "price1": "3.34"
    }
  },
  {
    "ddddd: {
      "value1": "cef3f",
      "price1": "1.1",
    }
  },
  {
    "rrrrr678": {
      "value1": "dfdf",
      "price1": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

class

```
public class itemList
{
    [JsonProperty("value1")]
    public string value1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price1")]
    public double price1 { get; set; }
}
```

cs:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, itemList>>(jsonFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do it this way (after correcting your JSON for the missing `"`:

Youe class would be:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("value1")]
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price1")]
    public double Price1 { get; set; }
}
```

And to deserialise, you need a list of dictionaries:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, Item>>>(jsonFile);
```

Comment: o, List Dictionary works like this way, but how to foreach it? It showing me like list of list. Not list item available. Only keys i can foreach without values.

Comment: Like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FPjhyL

Comment: Thank you a lot - it's working perfect, now i can go forward

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a typo, but the json code you uploaded is missing a quotation mark. The correct deserialization would be:

```cs
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, itemList>>>(jsonFile);
```

Fixed json code:

```json
[
  {
    "item1": {
      "value1": "rhe5h45h",
      "price1": "3.34"
    }
  },
  {
    "ddddd": {
      "value1": "cef3f",
      "price1": "1.1",
    }
  },
  {
    "rrrrr678": {
      "value1": "dfdf",
      "price1": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: When we see typos, we usually add a comment to fix them and close the question as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: @DavidG Unfortunately my reputation is below 50, which is required to write a comment below the question. Besides the typo, I also gave an answer, so I hope it's ok.

Comment: Then go get 50 rep, it doesn't take long at all, you can do that by suggesting edits. as for the answer you gave, now your question is identical to other ones already here. I'm not going to downvote your answer, but next time be more considerate.

Answer (score 0):

Use List

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, itemList>>>(jsonFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not Deserializing a Dictionary, this is an array (or list) of Key\Value pairs.

Your code could change to something like below to work.

`var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, itemList>>>(jsonFile);`

To deserialize a Dictionary the parser would expect a key vaule (unique key) pair such as the json below.

```
{
    "item1": {
        "value1": "rhe5h45h",
        "price1": "3.34"
    },
    "ddddd": {
        "value1": "cef3f",
        "price1": "1.1"
    },
    "rrrrr678": {
        "value1": "dfdf",
        "price1": "2"
    }
}
```